# Objective-C: printing enum values

Tags: objective-c, enums

I was trying to print out the enum constant in Objective-C on Xcode.

The code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        enum boolean{
            no, yes
        };

    NSLog(@"%d", yes);


    }

    return 0;

}
```

I ran this code and all the console is showing me is "(lldb)".

Is it the syntax that I got wrong?

Or am I missing something here?

Also, I tried it different way using typedef:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

     @autoreleasepool {

          typedef enum {
              no, yes
          } boolean;

         boolean boolVal = yes;

         NSLog(@"%d", boolVal);

     }

     return 0;
}
```

I suspect I did something wrong with printing out the value, with NSLog().

But I have tried using %i, %@, %d. But the output was same, (lldb).

Are there any different ways to print out the enum values?

Comment: If you are seeing the debugger prompt then either your app crashed or you set a breakpoint and the debugger stopped at the breakpoint.

Comment: @rmaddy YES! The statement NSLog() was on the green highlighted line, labeled on the right hand corner, was this "Thread 1: breakpoint 3.1", do you know what that means? Sorry, I am new to Objective-C.

Comment: Delete the breakpoint or click on the "play" icon in the debugger to continue execution.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you! That's the answer I was looking for! :D

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the members of the `enum` values is you want to print them. Try the following.

```
enum boolean {
    no  = 0,
    yes = 1
};

NSLog(@"yes = %d",yes);
```

The previous code outputs the following.

```
yes = 1
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @James That means your error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: I don't understand.. how come you compiled it and got the right output and I don't ?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to look for other kinds of unexpected errors.

Comment: @BrianTracy You do not need to give values to the enum members. They will be assigned numbers automatically, starting with 0.